# Name of my app is only showing up half below its icon

Tags: android

Is there a way to get my app name to show fully under its icon? The name is ( Nationals and Yorgey's ). But it only displays Nationals. How do i get the full name to show up?

Answer (score 0):

I have given double space between word and it works fine .

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned,your app name is Nationals and Yorgey's.You should use Nationals and Yorgeys in values/string.xml ( Nationals and Yorgeys)

Hope this will work.